# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed, Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I try to migrate db, but I got an error, and I am not sure why. Not sure what is "incorrectly formed".

```
//First Table
        Schema::create('lkp_anime_lists', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            //more columns here
        });
//Second one
        Schema::create('lkp_cards', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('lkp_anime_list_id');
        });

        Schema::table('lkp_cards', function ($table) {
            $table->foreign('lkp_anime_list_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('lkp_anime_lists')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `anime_db`.`lkp_cards` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `lkp_cards` add constraint `lkp_cards_lkp_anime_list_id_foreign` foreign key (`lkp_anime_list_id`) references `lkp_anime_lists` (`id`) on delete cascade)

Comment: Because `lkp_cards.lkp_anime_list_id` is unsigned and `lkp_anime_lists.id` isn't. So either remove the `->unsigned()` or add it to the `lkp_anime_lists` `$table->id()` above,

Comment: Initially was without, but still, I re-tested, and I got the same error.

Comment: Edit your post to show the code now that the signature of the two columns matches.

Comment: Ok, I did that.

Comment: The new version of Laravel makes the `id()` function alias to `bigIncrements` so you also need to change the `$table->integer('lkp_anime_list_id');` to `$table->bigInteger('lkp_anime_list_id');`

Comment: Sorry, but that's not correct. There can be only one auto column. I also tested to make sure. Also is not my first project in Laravel 7, but at this one I am not sure what it's not ok.

Comment: Funny I gave you the answer in the comment above, you said it's not correct, and then you accepted the same answer below. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('lkp_anime_list_id')
```

instead because of primary and foreign keys should be in the same data type

Comment: That's the answer, thank you! But you can tell my why on some other columns works just with "integer" ?

Comment: probably because of you created primary keys with "increments()" method which is was unsignedInteger. But now you started to use "id()" method which is unsignedBigInteger

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
$table->bigInteger('lkp_anime_list_id')->unsigned();
```

for Laravel version 6+